# Apache spark master server not starting. Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed apache spark by following these [instructions](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-18-04/). When I get to step 5, or when I have to execute `start-master.sh` in terminal I get the following output:

```
21/09/25 12:41:33 WARN Utils: Your hostname, petar-X580VD resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.0.105 instead (on interface wlp3s0)
21/09/25 12:41:33 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @4434095f
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:181)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:56)
    ... 13 more
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You could try to use an older Java version (9 or 11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @werner suggested in the comments, changing to java version 11 fixed the problem.